# Uploading to digital ocean spaces using pre-signed-url

Tags: cors, digital-ocean, pre-signed-url

I cant uploaded to my pre-signed-url

When i try uploading to the signed url, i get a CORS error

````
access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/bucket-name/ShFv9RJ7Pz8DPcKVM2JHVU9fQRwCPM38CT41x2YIcz7XdE9ZwQwzZlNuwe4GSm4z-2023-09-13T13%3A54%3A00?AWSAccessKeyId=DO00GQXYKPRWC8FPZJ92&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1694613540&Signature=lKpA7i8r5lJMZ3goTNu91OU%2Fd7g%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
upload.ts:29    



 PUT https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/bucket-name/ShFv9RJ7Pz8DPcKVM2JHVU9fQRwCPM38CT41x2YIcz7XdE9ZwQwzZlNuwe4GSm4z-2023-09-13T13%3A54%3A00?AWSAccessKeyId=DO00GQXYKPRWC8FPZJ92&Content-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=1694613540&Signature=lKpA7i8r5lJMZ3goTNu91OU%2Fd7g%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read net::ERR_FAILED
dispat```


i tried Configuring the CORS on digital ocean to allow origin localhost, but still the same error
````

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have CORS settings to be configured correctly at DO spaces:

   `origin` should contain the protocol, domain name, and port (if applicable) of the web site you're uploading from (e.g. it can be
   `http://localhost:3000` for localhost)

   `allowed methods` should be set correctly. You can enable all available at the DO config panel: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, HEAD

   you also might need to add a header to headers. For debug purposes, you can add `*` allowing all headers.
2. When generating pre-signed URL, you should specify the `content-type` (e.g. `image/jpg`), and it should be the same as you specify it when uploading the file